# How do I group related data into a batch on an insert using Declare Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table to select from, one table to update where I create a new transaction ID and another table to insert into using the transaction ID. I want to group all of my like transactions from the first table into one insert using the a transaction ID that is created on the update.

Here is the first tables data

[image: TimeCard Table]

This is the Query I am using now to select update and insert

```
DECLARE @TransactionNo int
Declare @Counter int
Declare @DateOut Date
Declare @Department_No nvarchar (100)
Declare @Job_Id nvarchar(50)



Declare Cur cursor for select  Counter, DateOut, Job, Department from [dbo].[TimeCards_Inv] 
open cur

fetch next from cur into @Counter, @DateOut, @Department_no,@Job_id

While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin

--creates a new transaction number

UPDATE cas_tekworks.dbo.next_number
SET next_trx = next_trx + 1
WHERE table_name_no='next_inventory_qty_jrnl'

Select @TransactionNo = [next_trx] From /cas_tekworks.dbo.next_number
WHERE table_name_no='next_inventory_qty_jrnl'
if @PunchType = 'O'

begin

-- Insert header record
INSERT INTO cas_tekworks.dbo.inventory_job_h
( transaction_no, dateout,job)
Select  @TransactionNo, @DateOut, @Job_ID
end
fetch next from cur into @Counter, @DateOut, @Department_no,@Job_id
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Currently this code creates a new transaction ID for each Line in the database but I would like it to create just 1 transaction when I group by job and department. These are the current results. In my scenario. I would like it just to have 160 for job 10000 not two transaction ids.

[image]

Comment: Tip: UPDATE allows retrieving values: `UPDATE cas_tekworks.dbo.next_number SET @TransactionNo = next_trx = next_trx + 1 WHERE table_name_no='next_inventory_qty_jrnl'`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want your update?

I mean if you want to add the number of line, why making a loop adding one, instead of doing a count adding the result?

You have this possibility if you want to add the count :

> UPDATE cas_tekworks.dbo.next_number
>   SET next_trx = next_trx + (select  count(*) from [dbo].[TimeCards_Inv]) --it's possible you have to do a distinct or something else here
>   WHERE table_name_no='next_inventory_qty_jrnl'

If you can add multiple values, it's still possible to do it in one operation. 
You can create a temp table with the appropriate values, and in your update you add an output clause saving all the information you need. In your case it would be job, date, id.
Then you can make an insert from the temp table.

Comment: I still need to loop at some point I think. I want to grab the new transaction id I just created and insert all of the records that have the same job into the next table with the same transaction ID, then go to the next group of jobs create a new transaction ID and insert those. etc.....

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating the transaction number first and then declaring a sub cursor  within the first. I also took out the counter ID  field and just grouped by job and department. While selecting date out I used MAX(dateout)